# Mongoose.remove callback not working in typescript (typing error)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am working on converting my web app to typescript and when I run the callback for Blogs.remove it return the following error.

```
Argument of type '(err: any, blog: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any) => void'.ts(2345)
```

the rout is

```
    Blogs.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err: any, blog:any){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        res.redirect("/blogs")
    }
})
```

Sorry if it is something silly I am new to typescript. Any help is apreciated.

Comment: `function(err: any){` instead of `function(err: any, blog:any){`

Comment: Oh, thanks. Appreciate it